# How to restore opened file after Vectorworks crash?

Tags: macos, restore, vectorworks

According to the Console app Vectorworks crashed because of an unhandled `NSImageCacheException`. For some reason, the file I was working on disappeared with the crash! How can I restore it?

Answer (score 1):

You have no real possibility to restore afterwards if you have not used some customs settings. So you can setup in the application settings, after how many steps or minutes it should create a backup to a customizable folder. So I know from ArchiCAD, that It will ask you to recover automatically after crash - it is not possible in Vectorworks.